# Python getting values in two separate lists

Tags: python

I have a fucntion returning two lists:

```
def get_ticket_queue()
    ...bunch of stuff
    return ticket_id_list,ticket_description_list
```

They both return the same amount of values, they are grabbing values from XML data. One grabs ticket_id, one grabs the ticket_summary

This is how I use it currently to determine if it's a good or bad ticket:

```
ticket_queue = get_ticket_queue()

for ticket_id in ticket_queue[0]:
    bad_ticket_id = next_steps(ticket_id) #next_steps is a separate function that performs some other work on the values.

    if "good" not in bad_ticket_id:
        print (bad_ticket_id)
    else:
        print "good:
```

That covers getting and using the ticket_id from the first list (ticket_id_list). However, when I print bad_ticket_id, I also need to grab the corresponding index value in the ticket_description_list so I can print the ticket_summary.

I hope that makes sense. There might be a better/easier way to do this but I'm not sure what that is. In short, I'm trying to figure out how to print both values at the same index from the two different lists.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: why not create tuples of ticket id + description? `zip(ticket_id_list,ticket_description_list)` that way you can iterate over the tuples and have both datapoints together...

Comment: There are many fixes for it, like @PatrickArtner suggested a tuple. I would personally go for a map with the key being the ticket_id.

Comment: didn't know those were a thing. Looking into them now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1:

This is a typical use case for the `enumerate()` iterator. The idea is to iterate on your `list1`, and get the corresponding element from `list2`:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']
list2 = ['x','y','z','t','u']

for i, e in enumerate(list1):
    print(e)            # This is your list1 element
    print(list2[i])     # This is the corresponding list2 element
```

In your specific case, your `list1` is `ticket_queue[0]`, and `list2` is `ticket_queue[1]`.

### Solution 2:

Let's reproduce your function:

```
def lists():
    return list1,list2
```

You can `zip()` together the two lists returned by the function, and iterate on two lists simultaneously. This is an iterator too, just like Solution 1, hence memory-friendly.

```
for one, two in zip(*lists()):
    print(one)
    print(two)
```

Let's fit this to your code fully:

```
ticket_queue = get_ticket_queue()

for ticket_id, ticket_summary in zip(*ticket_queue):
    bad_ticket_id = next_steps(ticket_id)    
    if "good" not in bad_ticket_id:
        print(bad_ticket_id)
        print(ticket_summary)
    else:
        print "good"
```